# Generic Multi level list view using array adapter in a drawer layout and passing JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, user-interface

I am creating a generic multi level list view in a navigation drawer layout.

The idea is to pass an array to list view that generates a new array or append array list and pass it every time a user touches a list item.

problems and possible solutions in this idea are

1. Each text view looks alike since list view contains only one text view in its adapter.
   solution: customizing the style of text view every time by overriding get view method of array adapter.
2. Collect data in multilevel dimension form from a JSON object
   solution: iterative search or data structure to serve the purpose.
3. There is a main activity and an asynchronous task that retrieve JSON object. The problem is if I call select item method from my main activity I cannot access to data since connection class does not terminate even after its post executes method.

Comment: The problem is broad and need your valuable suggestions

Comment: Add some code from what u have tryed.

Comment: I have dropped that idea. Sorry